# How to send high quality images to another view using collectionview

Tags: swift

**My question is really simple. I have a collectionView and I'm sending image from it to another view and showing it. But the problem is that the quality is really bad. I made collectionView from photolibrary using tutorial from youtube. Here's my code how I'm sending image.**

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let selectedCell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
    ujaj = selectedCell.imageView.image
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue077", sender: self)

}
```

**And my full code:**

import UIKit
import Photos
class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    @IBOutlet public var bandau: UIImageView!

```
var imageArray = [UIImage]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    grabPhotos()
}

func grabPhotos(){

    let imgManager = PHImageManager.default()

    let requestOptions = PHImageRequestOptions()
    requestOptions.isSynchronous = true
    requestOptions.deliveryMode = .highQualityFormat // Quality of images

    let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
    fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: false)]

    if let fetchResult : PHFetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: .image, options: fetchOptions) {

        if fetchResult.count > 0 {
            for i in 0..<fetchResult.count {
                imgManager.requestImage(for: fetchResult.object(at: i) as! PHAsset, targetSize: CGSize(width: 200, height: 200), contentMode: .aspectFill, options: requestOptions, resultHandler: {
                    image, error in
                    self.imageArray.append(image!)

                })
            }
        }
        else {
            print("You got no photos")
           //self.collectionView?.reloadData()
        }
    }

}

@IBOutlet weak var fakk: UIImageView!

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return imageArray.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {


    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell

    let imageView = cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UIImageView




    imageView.image = imageArray[indexPath.row]



    return cell
}


public var ujaj: UIImage?


@IBAction func kadsasd(_ sender: Any) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue077", sender: self)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let selectedCell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
    ujaj = selectedCell.imageView.image
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue077", sender: self)

}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let width = collectionView.frame.width / 3 - 1

    return CGSize(width: width, height: width)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 1.0
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 1.0
}



override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let main = segue.destination as! display



    main.image = ujaj
}
```

**Question is how to send FULL quality images? Because now I have 200x200 photos. If I change to higher then automatically my application crashes because of the memory. Maybe it's possible to get a full quality image when user clicks on the cell?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you have your indexPath I suggest you to convert it to Integer and then ask for a photo from library once again. Don't forget to change .targetSize to PHImageManagerMaximumSize also .contentMode to PHImageContentMode.default

**In your case:**

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {




    let index : Int = indexPath.row


    let imgManager = PHImageManager.default()

    let requestOptions = PHImageRequestOptions()
    requestOptions.isSynchronous = true
    requestOptions.deliveryMode = .highQualityFormat // Quality of images

    let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
    fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: false)]


    let fetchResult : PHFetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: .image, options: fetchOptions)

        imgManager.requestImage(for: fetchResult.object(at: index) , targetSize: PHImageManagerMaximumSize, contentMode: PHImageContentMode.default, options: requestOptions, resultHandler: {
            image, error in
            self.ujaj = image

        })

    performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue077", sender: self)
}
```